# Total variation of absolutely continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, absolute-continuity

I was trying to solve the following question:

> Let $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be absolutely continuous. That is,
>   \begin{equation}
> f(t)=f(0)+\int_{0}^{t} f'(s)ds  
> \end{equation}
>   for an integrable function $f'$. Let $V(t)$ be the total variation of $f$ in $[0,t]$. Show that 
>   \begin{equation}
> V(t)=\int_{0}^{t} |f'(s)|ds  
> \end{equation}

My attempt: Since $f$ is absolutely continous in $[0,t]$, it is also continuous. In particular, right-continuous. WLOG, assume $f(0)=0$. Then $f(t)=\mu((0,t])$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure associated with $f$. This implies, $\mu(A)=\int_{A}f'(s)ds$ for any Borel set $A$. This $\mu$ is a signed measure, and by Jordan decompostion, $\mu^{+}(A)=\int_{A}f'^{+}(s)ds$ and $\mu^{-}(A)=\int_{A}f'^{-}(s)ds$. Therefore, the total variation is $\mu^{+}+\mu^{-}=\int_{A}f'^{+}(s)ds+\int_{A}f'^{-}(s)ds=\int_{A}|f'(s)|ds$. Is this method right?

Comment: How can $f(0)$ be part of the answer? What if $f\equiv 1?$

Comment: @zhw. Sorry, edited. I did a copypasta of the previous equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is clear:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})| = \sum_{k=1}^{n}|\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k}f'| \le  \sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k}|f'|=\int_a^b |f'|.$$

Thus $V_{[a,b]}\le \int_a^b |f'|.$

A nice way to get the other direction is the following exercise: If $g\in L^1[a,b],$ then

$$\lim_{|P|\to 0} \sum_{k=1}^{n}|\int_{I_k}g| = \int_a^b|g|.$$

Here $P$ is a partition, and we are letting the mesh size $\to 0.$ A good way to prove this is to do it first for $g$ continuous, and then use the density of continuous functions in $L^1.$ I'll leave it here for now.

Comment: I understand how to do it this way. I was trying out a measure theoretic way by using the correspondence between functions of bounded variation and finite signed measures on the real line.