# Let $f\in AC[a,b]$, then the function $x\mapsto V_a^x(f)$ is absolutely continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let be $f\in AC[a,b]\subseteq BV[a,b]$ be an absolutely continuous function on $[a,b]$. We must prove that the function $$x\mapsto V_a^x(f)$$ is an absolutely continuous function.
We remember that $$V_a^x(f)=\sup_{\mathcal{P}\in\Pi_{[a,x]}} V_a^x(f,\mathcal{P}),$$ where $\Pi_{[a,x]}$ is the collecion of all partition of $[a,x]$, and if $\mathcal{P}=\{a=x_0\le x_1\le \cdots \le x_n=x \}$ is an arbitrary partition of $[a,x]$ we have that $$V_a^x(f,\mathcal{P})=\sum_{k=1}^n |f(b_k)-f(a_k)|.$$

For to prove that $V_a^x(f)\in AC[a,b]$ we must prove that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that for any finite collection of non-overlapping closed intervals $\{[a_l,b_l]\; |\; l=1,\dots, m\}$ contained in $[a,b]$ with $\sum_{l=1}^m(b_l-a_l)<\delta$, we have $\sum_{l=1}^m|V_a^{b_l}(f)-V_a^{a_l}(f)|<\varepsilon$.

Let $$\mathcal{P}_l=\{a_l\equiv x_l^{(0)}<x_l^{(1)}<\cdots<x_l^{(n_l)}\equiv b_l\}$$ a partition of $[a_l,b_l]$ for $l=1,\dots, m$. Note that $$\{[x_l^{k-1},x_l^{(k)}]\; :\; k=1,\dots n_l\}$$ is a finite collecion of non overlapping closed intervals contained in $[a,b]$. Also

$$\sum_{l=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^{n_l} \left(x_l^{(k)}-x_l^{(k-1)}\right)=\sum_{l=1}^m(b_l-a_l)<\delta.$$ Now, since $f\in AC[a,b]$ we have that $$\sum_{l=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^{n_l} \left|f\left(x_l^{(k)}\right)-f\left(x_l^{(k-1)}\right)\right|=\sum_{l=1}^m V_{a_l}^{b_l}(f,\mathcal{P_l})<\varepsilon.$$ Then, $$\sum_{l=1}^m V_{a_l}^{b_l}(f,\mathcal{P_l})<\varepsilon$$

> For the arbitrary of partition $\mathcal{P_l}$ can I conclude that $$\sum_{l=1}^m V_{a_l}^{b_l}(f)<\varepsilon?\tag1$$

I'm not sure, in fact we have $$\sum_{l=1}^m V_{a_l}^{b_l}(f)=\sum_{l=1}^m\sup_{\mathcal{P}\in \Pi_{[a_l,b_l]}}V_{a_l}^{b_l}(f,\mathcal{P})\ge \sum_{l=1}^m V_{a_l}^{b_l}(f,\mathcal{P}_l)$$

If the answer to question $(1)$ were true the result would follow easily. If the answer to question $(1)$ is false, how can I prove the result?

**EDIT** I had an idea.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ fixed. Let $\{[a_l,b_l]\;|\; l=1,\dots, m\}$ a finite collection of non overlapping closed intervals in $[a,b]$ such that $\sum_{l=1}^m (b_l-a_l)<\delta$ (such $\delta>0$ exists since $f\in AC([a,b]))$

For all $l=1,\dots, m$ exists a partition $\mathcal{P}_l$ of $[a_l,b_l]$ such that $$V_{a_l}^{b_l}(f)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2m}< V_{a_l}^{b_l}(f,\mathcal{P}_l).\tag2$$ We say that $$\mathcal{P}_l=\{a_l\equiv x_l^{(0)}<x_l^{(1)}<\cdots<x_l^{(n_l)}\equiv b_l\}.$$

Then for all $l=1\dots, m$ $$\{[x_l^{(k-1)}, x_l^{(k)}]\;|\; k=1,\dots n_l\}$$ is a finite collection of non overlapping closed intervals contained in $[a,b]$ and $$\sum_{l=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^{n_l} \left(x_l^{(k)}-x_l^{(k-1)}\right)=\sum_{l=1}^m(b_l-a_l)<\delta.$$ Now, since $f\in AC[a,b]$ we have that $$\sum_{l=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^{n_l} \left|f\left(x_l^{(k)}\right)-f\left(x_l^{(k-1)}\right)\right|=\sum_{l=1}^m V_{a_l}^{b_l}(f,\mathcal{P_l})<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$ Then, $$\sum_{l=1}^m V_{a_l}^{b_l}(f,\mathcal{P_l})<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$

For $(2)$ we have that $$\sum_{l=1}^m V_{a_l}^{b_l}(f)<\sum_{l=1}^m\frac{\varepsilon}{2m}+\sum_{l=1}^m V_{a_l}^{b_l}(f,\mathcal{P}_l)<\varepsilon.$$

it's a good idea?

Comment: This seems to be quite complicated an approach. Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3613926/total-variation-of-absolutely-continuous-function) help you?

Comment: @LNT Thanks, but I want to do it with definitions, without the fundamental theorem.

Comment: After reading your whole post, your idea seems fine. In fact, you already proved it before the edit was made because you showed $\sum_{l=1}^m V_{a_l}^{b_l} (f, \mathcal P_l) < \epsilon$ for all partitions $\mathcal P_l$, and taking the supremum for each $l$ is enough to show (1). Which is essentially the same in your Edit part